# Installing same packages in pip3 as in pip

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am using both python 2.7 now added python 3.4.

How I could easy migrate packages installed via pip to pip3?

A followup for the future: is there a way to install packages to both 2.7 and 3.4 version of python?

**Edit 1: combining answers.**
**Edit 2: moved solution to an answer.**

Comment: Globally? In the same virtualenv? Are all the packages both Python2 and Python3 compatible? Have you looked at simply `pip freeze > packages.txt` followed by `pip3 install -r packages.txt`?

Comment: Thanks that worked fine after removing the outdated packed. As a matter of fact all 100+ worked expect memche which have been renamed to memche3 :)

Comment: FYI you can answer your own question and accept your own answer. I personally think what you did is fine for people who get here from Google but the former may be more appropriate, at least in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved to the answer as suggested by Two-Bit Alchemist.

first updated all the packages

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U
```

Then I "reinstalled"to python 3

```
brew install pip3
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -sfnv ../Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/bin/python3 python
unset PYTHONPATH
eval 'export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages'
```

and then reinstall to python 3

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip3 install
```

I packed it all in a bash function and now it's all automated for simple future use! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

pip is a program that installs the appropriate version of a python package (using its metadata) to pythonx.y/lib/site-packages for some values of x and y.  On *nix, the default x.y is the latest version of python2.  pip3 is an alias that changes the default to the latest version of python3.

```
pip -h
```

lists the pip commands and general options.

```
pip command -h
```

lists the options for `command`, such as `install`.

Taken literally, migrating 'to pip3' is not meaningful.  Getting the same packages installed for 3.4 that you have installed for 2.7 is, of course.  The method given by Two-Bit Alchemist should work for every package that is compatible with 3.x, though I believe requirement files are meant for copying a pythonx.y installation to another pythonx.y installation (possibly in a virtual environment).  It will install the same x.y.z version of the package that you already have, even if outdated, so you might want to update your 2.7 collections first with

```
pip install -U <package>
```

for each package.

Comment: What you say is true -- `pip freeze` output hardcodes version numbers.

Comment: running pip install -U was a great idea!